# Структура изучения Python

Tags: python, веб-программирование, backend

Всем привет! Если вопрос поднимался прошу указать ссылку.

Суть такова: изучаю пайтон, планирую стать бэкенд девом. Изучив вопрос самообразования в сфере составил определнный план изучения технологий и азы пайтона начал изучать с интерактивных курсов;
Дошел до классов и увидел как поверхостно они растолкованы в курсе, обратился к Марку Лутцу и реально удивился как обьемно и понятно там раскрыта эта тема. В этот момент я понял, что попал в ловушку, т к видимо все темы до классов в курсе раскрыты точно так же поверхностно.
Теперь передо мной стоит вопрос, лететь дальше, попутно доучивая непонятные моменты и уже переходить к смежным технологиям для бэкенд (соответственно начинать практиковаться) и фреймворкам пайтона, или брать паузу и начинать изучение пайтона как бы сначала но уже по Лутцу(читать оба тома,что затратит приличный обьем времени который я мог бы потратить на изучение того же джанго). На что целесообразней будет потратить время?

P.S. Заранее благодарю

P.P.S Сори за грамотность, если кому принципиально

Comment: Я голосую за лететь дальше. Если какая-то тема не понятно - изучать ее подробнее. Возвращаться и начинать с нуля - пустая трата времени, ИМХО.

Comment: Благодарю!Тут больше вопрос того,так ли важно глубокое понимание работы языка для backend на пайтоне

Comment: суть такова, что не получится стать онли джанго девом, ибо программирование как таковое предполагает знания в больших сферах, и тут не пойдет просто знание фреймворка и основ синтаксиса, по этому я бы порекомендовал идти в обе стороны - учить фреймворк и тянуть знания по питону на более пристойный уровень. ибо дальше может понадобиться переходить на другие динамические языки, например js, и тут хорошее знание питона очень даже поможет, ибо структурно языки похожи

Comment: Знания фреймворков и худо-бедно сделанные работы помогут быстрее получить работу хотя бы джуном. Хорошее и глубокое понимание языка позволит вам расти как программисту выше джуна и не спотыкаться в местах, где задача решается в десятки раз проще. Поэтому тут палка о двух концах, нужно и то и то.

Comment: Всем спасибо, суть уловил :)

Comment: @bestpilotingalaxy именно для backend глубокое и всестороннее знание языка не требуется. Изучению js глубокое знание python тоже не сильно поможет (языки не настолько сильно похожи), или поможет, но настолько же, насколько знание любого другого современного языка программирования. В остальном с Alex Krass согласен.